# Visual Studio build debug target .exe file-name mismatch

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2017, target, mismatch

I am trying to build and run one demo in Visual Studio 2017.
But with compilation, the debug mode target gets the name with 'D' suffix instead of without it. (Specifically PDIconsoleD.exe instead of PDIconsole.exe) But when trying to run project already built project, it cannot find the file, because it looks for the name without this suffix (PDIconsole.exe).

I tried to run the file from the file browser, it got error, that I would like to debug.

Many thanks

PL.

Comment: Take a look into your Project settings: *Configuration Properties -> general : Target name / output directory* | *Linker -> general -> output file*... they are different for Debug/Release *Configuration*...

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project properties and check what is target name on different configurations. It might be that on debug mode it is changed to add suffig of `'D'` so just delete that so it will be the same name for debug and release.

[image: Properties]